# How to send message from RSU periodically In the RSUExampleScenario in Veins 4.6?

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

In my simulation, I want to make RSU (RoadSide Unit) send message every 30 seconds to the vehicles in the range. In another work, the WSM messages are generated by RSU, and will be received by vehicles. How can I possibly change the provided [TraCIDemoRSU11p.cc](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/master/src/veins/modules/application/traci/TraCIDemoRSU11p.cc) in Veins 4.6 to do this? I know [handlePositionUpdate](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/master/src/veins/modules/application/traci/TraCIDemo11p.cc#L78) is used for the mobility module. But since the position of RSU is not changing, does this function work for RSU?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can schedule an event as a self-message (e.g. [BaseWaveApplLayer.cc:106](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4.6/src/veins/modules/application/ieee80211p/BaseWaveApplLayer.cc#L106)) and upon receiving this event send your WSM and re-schedule the event (e.g. [BaseWaveApplLayer.cc:239](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4.6/src/veins/modules/application/ieee80211p/BaseWaveApplLayer.cc#L239)).

Comment: @Jia Guo: if you like this answer, please mark it as solution such that other people can benefit from it.